# PHP Regular Expression for currency

Tags: php, regex

I am curious about finding a regular expression for dollars.  My inputs and rules are that there can only be digits 0 to 9 and an optional deciaml point. If the decimal exists, it must have two 0 t 9 digits after it.

So it can except:
1000
1000.99

But not:
10001.1
1000.
1,000
$100.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{2}){0,1}$/
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you know anything about regular expressions?
Let me explain the solution:

1)you want digits, those are `[0-9]`

2)you want at least one of them, which is `+`

3)then there may be something, lets put it into brackets, 0 or 1 times means `?`

so you have now this `[0-9]+(something)?`

4)now you want in something to be decimal point, dot is special char in regex so you have to escape it `\.`

5)then you want numbers again, exactly two of them which is `{2}`

Here you are, full expression:

```
 $expression="/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{2})?/";
```

Answer (score 0):

This will check arbitrary amounts:

```
/^(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?:,[0-9]{3})*(?:|\.[0-9]+)$/
```

E.g. it will validate:

```
1,432.33
  342
    1.2
    0.343
```