# Check a text field for currency value

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to check a text field to make sure only a numbers and decimals are present. The text field will be submitted via the $_POST[""] method.

**I'd like to make sure only values like these are submitted.**

```
10
20.4
19.99
0.75
```

**I'd like to make sure these values are not submitted.**

```
10 dollars
20 and .40
Ten Dollars
$10,000.15
```

**I'm confused as to which of these I should use to check the variable value**

```
ctype_digit
is_int
is_numeric
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: bool is_numeric ( mixed $var ) - http://php.net/is_numeric

Comment: Use a regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647965/php-regular-expression-for-currency

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['field']) && is_numeric($_POST['field']) && $_POST['field'] > 0) { }
```

Let's break this down.

Make sure `$_POST['field']` actually exists:

```
isset($_POST['field'])
```

Exists? Good. Is it [numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)?

```
is_numeric($_POST['field'])
```

Yes? Fantastic. Now it's numeric, make sure people enter positive values (if that is what you desire)

```
$_POST['field'] > 0
```

(or of course, `>=`, up to you)

Let's add one more step to ensure that if it follows these rules, it's also only two decimals or less.

```
if(strpos($_POST['field'], '.') !== false) {
    $decimals =  explode('.', $_POST['field']);
    if(strlen($decimals[1]) <= 2) {
         //proceed
    } else {
         //should error
} else {
     //proceed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to use `is_numeric` because `is_int` and `ctype_digit` are not checking for floats, only for integers.

As pointed out in comments. `is_numeric` also accepts scientific notations, binary, octal and hexadecimal.

To narrow it down to floats, int and scientific notation you should use `is_float` but there still is the scientific notation, then you can add a simple check with `strpos`.
Final code would look like this:

```
def is_simple_float(x):
    return is_float(x) && strpos(x, 'e') === false
```

The `===` means that you chack the values *and* the type of the variables (to ensure that if the `'e'` is at position 0 it does not return true).

Comment: `is_numeric` will accept `1e4`, `1e-2` as numeric values.

Comment: Yes and also 0x1212 and some more in fact.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably use RegEx for this...

```
<?php
function clean_decimal($string){
    $string = !empty($string) ? $string : "10 dollars";
    $string = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/i","",$string);
    return number_format(doubleval($string),2,".",",");;
}
```